# Why can this function return a null possibly?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, guava

Imagine I had a guava helper function

```
private Function<Config, Predicate<String>> makeFunctionToCompareTwoPathStrings() throws ConfigException {
    return new Function<Config, Predicate<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate<String> apply(final Config config) {
            try {
                final Path input = computationThatMightThrowAnException();
                return new Predicate<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean apply(String actual) {
                        return input.toAbsolutePath().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(actual);
                    }
                };
            } catch (ConfigException | URISyntaxException weDontReallyCareAboutItForThisTest) {
                log.error(weDontReallyCareAboutItForThisTest.getMessage());
            }
            // should always return a predicate if nothing returned yet, simply return an alwaysFalse predicate
            return Predicates.alwaysFalse();
        }
    };
}
```

When I'm using this:

**EDIT:**

```
Config config = Config.getInstance();
makeFunctionToCompareTwoPathStrings().apply(config).apply(config.getInput());
```

I get a warning

> Dereferencing possible null pointer

in this line at the outermost `apply` - that one on the predicate - which I don't understand.

**EDIT:**

A little redundant but useful `Predicates.or` obviously makes things clearer for the analyser :) :

```
Predicates.or(makeFunctionToCompareTwoPathStrings().apply(config)).apply(config.getInput());
```

Comment: Could the object 'config' (non-capital c) be null at that point ?

Comment: There isn't enough information to find out what can possibly be null. We know `make....()` doesn't return null and neither do any of the functions/predicates. So it has got to be `config` but there's no context given in the question. (I know, I've contradicted myself here a bit :))

Comment: `Config.getInstance()` - what does this return?

Comment: to answer the questions, `Config.getInstance()` should return an Object I name it `config` here which is in turn providing a `String` on calling `getInput()`, one might also give an empty test string like in `...(config).apply("")` here and the warning won't disappear. I guess @jb-nizet is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the warning you get doesn't come from a very smart analysis of what your code actually does. It's probably only using the annotation on the Function.apply() method, which is declared as `@Nullable`, meaning that a apply() is *allowed* to return null. Your specific function does not, but the code checker isn't smart enough to know.